# Using 3d-models from local storage in Unity AR app ? (IPhone and Android)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I've made an AR app (proof of concept), which is bundled with a specific 3d-model at the moment.

Next step is to be able to select between a selection of 3d-models, stored on the users local storage on their phone/tablet, so user can select which 3d-model he wants to see.

I'm fairly new to Unity, and my limitations comes quickly, so i'm wondering if this is even possible, and if you guys have any resources or guide on how to do this ?

[image]

Comment: What is your specific coding related issue you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of plugin [UnityNativeFilePicker](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker) to easily access user's local files in iOS and Android.

Then to import your 3D models into Unity only FBX, OBJ, DAE and DXF are supported ([Unity 3D formats)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html) by default, but you can find really good runtime importers such as [glTFast](https://github.com/atteneder/glTFast) to import glTF files. It only depends on which file format you want to support in your app.

Comment: Thanks @AlexAR :) Will look at the UnityNativeFilePicker.. Do you by any chance... have some good resources on how to actually import this and replace the current "default" 3d-model (asset) already existing in the project, and replace it in the scene ?

Comment: @AlexAR did you get this to work on a Quest? Something in its VR applications seems to block getting the selected file returned to the VR app.